# I cannot understand which this code doesn't compile because of return statement

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Test{
   public static int[] calculateFactors(int n){
      int[] array = new int[n];
      for(int i = 0; i<=n;i++){
         if(n%i==0){
            return array[i];
         }
      }
   }

   public static void main(String[] args){
      System.out.println("Please enter the number you want to find the factors for:");
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      int n = input.nextInt();
      System.out.println(calculateFactors(n));
   }
}
```

I don't understand why I get an error. I am trying to write  a code where a user inputs a number and the program returns all the factors of this number.
Could anyone please tell me why when I am not being able to return the array with corresponding i factors.

Thank you

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Look at your code (whitespace added for clarity):

```
public static int[] calculateFactors(int n) {
    int[] array = new int[n];
    for(int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
        if(n % i == 0) {
            return array[i];
        }
    }
}
```

There are two problems:

- Your return statement doesn't match the declared return type. You're trying to return an `int`, but your method declares that it returns an `int[]`
- As your method is non-void, the end of the method has to be unreachable... you *have* to return a value through any possible path. That's not the case with your code. What happens if `n` is -1? It will never go through the loop, so it will never return. More generally, the compiler will assume that (almost) any `if` condition *may* be false.

Now, as to how to fix it - given the method name, it sounds like you really *do* want to return all the factors... so you shouldn't return as soon as you've found the *first* one. I'd collect the factors in a `List<Integer>` instead of in an array. Convert the `return` statement to an `add` call, and then return at the end of the loop. Oh, and you probably want to start the loop with `i` as 1 rather than 0...

All of this is specific to this particular problem though. More generally, you should look at the errors that the compiler's giving you. They should give you all the information you need to work this out for yourself. Now that you *do* understand the problem, read the messages again and try to work out what stopped you from understanding it before. Could you have worked it out yourself, or were you missing some important concept?

Comment: you always steal the limelight :)

Comment: `start the loop with i as 1 ` - or more precisely start with `2`.

Comment: @BhavikShah.. No. Limelight immerge from there only. He is the source. ;)

Comment: @RohitJain: Well it depends on how you want to define it, but I'd say that 1 is a factor of any positive integer. (This isn't looking for primes, just factors.)

Comment: @JonSkeet.. Yeah, that's why I said, as `1` is a factor of every number, so it doesn't need a test. May be the `list` can be initialized with a factor `1` in the beginning only. But of course that really does make much of a difference at all. But for sure avoids one extra check and an iteration :)

Comment: @user1804697.. Remember to mark this answer as accepted after `4 minutes` from now. You need to click the arrow besides it.

Comment: @RohitJain: It just makes it less elegant, IMO - and makes it give the wrong answer for 0 :) (I didn't see you say "as 1 is a factor of any number" anywhere - you just said to start at 2...)

Comment: @JonSkeet.. Oh yeah. As far as `0` is concerned that would fail. And actually I didn't say that `I already said that`. Actually I added it in that comment only. May be I framed it wrongly. Anyways, it makes sense now to start loop with `1`. :)

Comment: @RohitJain: I'm not sure how I should read "that's why I said" then... it certainly makes it sound like you'd already written that part before, and were having to reiterate your position. As I say, I can't see that explanation anywhere earlier in the comment history. We should probably stop the comment chat now though :)

Answer (score 2):

A return is missing in case of reaching the end of the loop

Answer (score 1):

Two errors
First:

```
for(int i = 0; i<=n;i++){
```

should be

```
for(int i = 0; i<n;i++){
```

Second:

```
 for(int i = 0; i<=n;i++){
  if(n%i==0){
    return array[i];
  }
}
```

should be

```
for(int i = 0; i<=n;i++){
    if(n%i==0){
       return array[i];
    }
 }
return something
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with statement:

```
 return array[i];
```

that is invalid because you are trying to return in index of the array which is an int where your method signature is returning int[] change to this

```
 return array;
```